# Yii2:using kartik date range picker for filtering in gridview

Tags: php, gridview, filter, yii2

I am trying to use the Kartik Date Range picker for filter in gridview.

I have a column date_time field as `discharge_date`, the widget is showing fine in the gridview but the filtering is not working at all.

This is my code in the Gridview:

```
[
                'attribute'=>'discharge_date',
                'value'=>'discharge_date',                
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE_RANGE,
                'filterWidgetOptions' =>([
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'discharge_date',
                'presetDropdown'=>TRUE,                
                'convertFormat'=>true,                
                'pluginOptions'=>[                                          
                    'format'=>'Y-m-d',
                    'opens'=>'left'
                ]
            ])

            ],
```

Where I am going wrong?

[image: Discharge Date]

Answer (score 8):

You need to parse the discharge_date filter value in your Search model. As an example the following code will take the filter value and split it on the dash and add the $start_date and $end_date to the $query string (i.e. add it after *if (!$this->validate()) {*):

```
if ( ! is_null($this->discharge_date) && strpos($this->discharge_date, ' - ') !== false ) {
    list($start_date, $end_date) = explode(' - ', $this->discharge_date);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'data_date', $start_date, $end_date]);
    $this->discharge_date = null;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful, the only comment about this is that if you null it you lost the selection in the date range after search.

Comment: I've used and followed the steps given in demo (kartik daterange) filter also but it not works to me. May I know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

make a pluginEvent configuration and trim your query for the date filter value.
ex:

ModelSearch:

```
...
  $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->'name']); //this line is for reference

            if(isset ($this->only_date)&&$this->only_date!=''){ //you dont need the if function if yourse sure you have a not null date
              $date_explode=explode(" - ",$this->only_date);
              $date1=trim($date_explode[0]);
              $date2=trim($date_explode[1]);
              $query->andFilterWhere(['between','only_date',$date1,$date2]);
            }


        return $dataProvider;
...
```

column:

```
...
    [
      'attribute'=>'only_date',
      'options' => [
          'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ],        
      'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE_RANGE,
      'filterWidgetOptions' => ([       
        'attribute' => 'only_date',
        'presetDropdown' => true,
        'convertFormat' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
          'separator' => ' - ',
          'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          'locale' => [
                'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            ],
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
          "apply.daterangepicker" => "function() { apply_filter('only_date') }",
        ],
      ])
    ],
...
```